# How can I count the number of folders in a specific folder level using Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, music, libraries

I have a very specific directory tree on my music library. I would like to count all of the albums, excluding all the subdirectories.

For instance, given this directory tree:

```
/music/
/music/Davis, Miles/                           
/music/Davis, Miles/Kind of Blue/                
/music/Davis, Miles/Tutu/                    
/music/Hendrix, Jimi/                              
/music/Hendrix, Jimi/Axis Bold As Love/               
/music/Hendrix, Jimi/Electric Ladyland/              
/music/Hendrix, Jimi/Electric Ladyland/Disk 1   
/music/Hendrix, Jimi/Electric Ladyland/Disk 2
```

I would like the command to return "4" .

So basically I want the command to return the number of albums, 
or, bonus points if it returns "2" Interprets and "4" albums.

(And double bonus points if it additionally lists the interprets and albums.)

How can I most easily do this?

Comment: What is an "interpret"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the four albums:

```
$ ls -d1 music/*/*/
music/Davis, Miles/Kind of Blue/
music/Davis, Miles/Tutu/
music/Hendrix, Jimi/Axis Bold As Love/
music/Hendrix, Jimi/Electric Ladyland/
```

To count them:

```
$ printf "%q\n" music/*/*/ | wc -l
4
```

The `%q` format is used here to prevent album names with newlines from being counted more than once.

To see the artists:

```
$ ls -d1 music/*/
music/Davis, Miles/
music/Hendrix, Jimi/
```

To count the number of artists:

```
$ printf "%q\n" music/*/ | wc -l
2
```

The above commands assume that `music` is in the current directory.  If the `music` directory is actually `/music`, then put a `/` in front of `music` in all of the above commands.  Otherwise, put in front whatever path will reach `music`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to list all the subdirectories. Then just count the number of slashes per line and report how often there were 3 of them:

```
find -type d | sed s%[^/]%%g | grep -c ^///$
```

Use `^//$` to get the number of interprets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a little 'find' magic.  Running

```
find /music -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d | wc -l
```

should give you the number of albums in your collection.  Running

```
find /music -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

should return the number of artists.